# What is the xpath for this upload button?

Tags: selenium, xpath

This is a dropdown menu. Can someone help to write the relative xpath for this to use as a locator in selenium automation?

[image]

I have tried with `//a[text='Upload']`

Comment: What you you trying to do with that xpath? To upload file by `send_keys()` method? What error you see with your current XOath?

Comment: Trying to click a button using the xpath

Comment: //a[text()='Upload'] is not locating the upload button.

Comment: And? What is the error? Show us your code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You try by right clicking the element in the browser under inspect element to get this [(here showing post your answer in stack overflow for example, after the right click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBMJd.png) then copying the XPATH, this would give another way of the same xpath, and referring this xpath might be a solution to your problem.